# Note down the possible states in a truth table.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

You are required to automate the control of the water tank in your home. There are two water
contact sensors that turn to a TRUE state when in contact with water and a FALSE state when not.
Sensor $1 (S_1)$ to detect water at the maximum level of the tank and sensor $2 (S_2)$ detects water
level at the minimum level. The electronically controlled tap (T) must turn off (FALSE) when the
water level reaches $S_1$ and the tap turn on (TRUE) when the water level drops to $S_2$. There is a
State Register $(S_R)$ which changes state if and only if $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_R$ are all the same state (i.e. $S_1$
TRUE, $S_2$ TRUE and $S_R$ TRUE then $S_R$ changes to FALSE or $S_1$ FALSE, $S_2$ FALSE and $S_R$
FALSE then $S_R$ changes to TRUE).

My problem is, Consider the output of this system as the state of T. Note down the possible states of this
system in a truth table.

Here the table I did but I am not sure. please tell me If it is correct or not? if it is not please explain right way,

Any help would be greatly appreciate!

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c|c} S1 & S2 &S_R & T(Result) \\[1ex]\hline T & T & F & F \\[1ex] F & T & F & T \\[1ex] F & T & T & T \end{array}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are three inputs in your system, the truth table should have $2^3$ rows:

$$
\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c|c} S_1 & S_2 &S_R & T_\text{Result} & S'_R & \text{remark}\\[1ex]\hline 
F & F & F & T & T & \text{tank empty} \\[1ex]
F & F & T & T & T & \text{tank empty} \\[1ex]
F & T & F & F & F & \text{tank contains water} \\[1ex]
F & T & T & F & T & \text{tank contains water} \\[1ex]
T & F & F & F & F & \text{tank max reached, S2 sensor failure} \\[1ex]
T & F & T & F & F & \text{tank max reached, S2 sensor failure} \\[1ex]
T & T & F & F & F & \text{tank max reached} \\[1ex]
T & T & T & F & F & \text{tank max reached}\\[1ex]
\end{array}}
$$

The tap state does not depend on the state register $S_R$. Therefore, a truth table with two inputs would suffice to describe the tap control. However, the subsequent state register $S'_R$ does depend on all three inputs.

The purpose of the state register $S_R$ is not clear from the question.

The outputs could be expressed as

$$T_\text{Result} = \neg S_1 \land \neg S_2$$

$$S'_R = \neg S_1 \land (\neg S_2 \lor S_R)$$

Comment: I think something is wrong. we don't want to exist the tank as empty, water must be between  $S_2$ and $S_1$

Comment: How can it be possible tank max reached but $S_2$ Sensor failure

Comment: Imagine, that the tank is newly built in. Sensor $S_2$ might be faulty. If that can be ruled out, you can assign a value for this non-existant case. This might be useful to minimize the logic. The tap should be controlled in such a way, that tank overflow is absolutely prevented.

Comment: please read my truth table

Comment: Your [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) is incomplete. It has only $3$ rather than $8$ rows. It lacks the second output column for the new value of $S_R$. Even if you exclude certain input combinations, you should declare them (for instance as don't case terms). If you disregard $S_R$ as input, you need four rows to express all combinations of $S_1$ and $S_2$. If you assume $S_2$ as always true (as shown in your table), two rows would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you I'm wrong